# WakeOnLan on Mac with Windows

Tags: windows-8, wake-on-lan, mac-pro

I have a Mac Pro (tower) with Windows 8 installed on it. I'm having troubles with enabling wakeOnLan through wifi. Although it seems the adapter supports it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn on Windows 8's "Hybrid Shutdown" feature.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2776718

Comment: it was on, I tried to switch if off and back on - nothing

Comment: 1: Open the Power Option in the Control Panel
2: Select "Choose what the power buttons do"
3: Uncheck "Turn on fast startup (recommended)"
4: Select "Save settings"

Turn on your PC, use your phone, tablet, other computer, etc. to send a magic-packet to your PC. Should work. If you're trying from outside the network, be sure to forward port 9 to your PC's local IP address.

Comment: nope... doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried checking your Energy Saver settings in Mac OS X? Check System Preferences > Energy Saver to be sure the Wake for Ethernet Network Access is selected under the Power Adapter profile.

Comment: I have no MacOS anymore, only Windows...

Comment: Due you have the right drivers? Or are you using the Windows proprietary drivers?

Comment: yes, there's nothing wrong with the drivers. I think it's just kinda impossible through wifi... Mac has to be connected via cable

Comment: Most likely. Hence why I build my own towers. :P